# How do the Assemblies of God interpret 1 Corinthians 11:2–6?

Tags: exegesis, 1-corinthians, pentecostalism, clothing

I attend an Assemblies of God church and my pastor's attitude towards expectation of attire within the church is very lax. That being the case, what is the AG/Pentecostal interpretation of [1 Corinthians 11:2–6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+corinthians+11%3A2-6&version=KJV)?

> 2 Now I praise you, brethren, that ye remember me in all things, and keep the ordinances, as I delivered them to you.
>
> 3 But I would have you know, that the head of every man is Christ; and the head of the woman is the man; and the head of Christ is God.
>
> 4 Every man praying or prophesying, having his head covered, dishonoureth his head.
>
> 5 But every woman that prayeth or prophesieth with her head uncovered dishonoureth her head: for that is even all one as if she were shaven.
>
> 6 For if the woman be not covered, let her also be shorn: but if it be a shame for a woman to be shorn or shaven, let her be covered. (KJV)

Comment: Are you asking only about the issue of head coverings in worship for men and women?  Or also about hair length of women?  Some Pentecostals hold that women should only have long hair.

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm asking particularly in regards to the beliefs of the Assemblies of God denomination on this scripture. My church is very lax and nontraditional in the way that people dress. People wear football jersies, basketball shorts, baseball caps, etc to church on Sunday. If they find that to be acceptable, then how do they interpret these verses?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the Assemblies of God does not have an official stance on physical head covering. The woman is free to decide.

At my church, Findlay First Assembly of God (the oldest AG Church), it was interpreted as a spiritual or metaphorical covering, refering to women in leadership positions over men within the church.

> The women in Corinth, by prophesying without a head covering, were sending a signal that they were no longer submitting to male authority. Paul sees this problem as severe because the arrogation of male leadership roles by women ultimately dissolves the distinction between men and women.
>   - Thomas R. Schreiner

[What Paul Really Says About Women in Ministry](http://enrichmentjournal.ag.org/201502/201502_070_Paul_women_ministry.cfm)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers.

Comment: And yet Paul taught that in Christ there is neither male nor female.  Galatians 3.28, which would suggest that the distinction between men and women has been removed in Christ.c